# How to place 2 columns closer together in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to increase a massive gap between 2 columns and give the text a smaller width while havig it all still centered.

as you can see they are very spread apart and I would really like the gap to be minimal as well as the width of the text. I'd like to try and get the left image right corner and the right image left corner to be under the program text.
[image]

here is my code:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <p class="text-center program-head">Programs</p>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="text-center">
                <img alt="" class="resize-image" id="image1" src=
                "/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/april2.jpg">
                <p class="program-text">Creative Writing</p>
                <p>This will help unleash a childs mind throught their own
                words. The imagination has no limit to a young childs mind.
                this is future forever in life yes hold me
                now</p><button class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="text-center">
                <img alt="" class="resize-image" id="image2" src=
                "/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/kids.png">
                <p class="program-text">Improv &amp; Comedy</p>
                <p>This improv class is a fun and non-stressful way to
                encourage children and young adults to communicate and
                build confidence! Students will learn how to think on their
                feet when expanding on an idea, story, or debate. These
                classes are inspired by <a href=
                "http://www.zipzapzopimprov.com/">Zip Zap
                Zop</a></p><button class="btn btn-primary">Learn
                More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about padding ?

[Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/5kLdurmb/1/)

```
.col-md-6 p { padding: 0 45px; }
```

Comment: yeah that actually worked for the text now I just need the images to be closer together

Comment: if you're using bootstrap, you have to change the col-md-6 by col-md-4 with 3 columns for example.
Otherwise, there will be a blank area. 
**OR**, you can increase image width (if there are good quality images)

Comment: okay! Thank you! I realized I did set a size for my images. Got it figured out now

Answer (score 2):

change class both div tag which has class='col-md-6' to class='col-md-4' and put one div tab between them with class='col-md-2' and write your text here

Like as below :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <p class="text-center program-head">Programs</p>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="text-center">
                <img alt="" class="resize-image" id="image1" src=
                "/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/april2.jpg">
                <p class="program-text">Creative Writing</p>
                <p>This will help unleash a childs mind throught their own
                words. The imagination has no limit to a young childs mind.
                this is future forever in life yes hold me
                now</p><button class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
               your text here
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="text-center">
                <img alt="" class="resize-image" id="image2" src=
                "/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/kids.png">
                <p class="program-text">Improv &amp; Comedy</p>
                <p>This improv class is a fun and non-stressful way to
                encourage children and young adults to communicate and
                build confidence! Students will learn how to think on their
                feet when expanding on an idea, story, or debate. These
                classes are inspired by <a href=
                "http://www.zipzapzopimprov.com/">Zip Zap
                Zop</a></p><button class="btn btn-primary">Learn
                More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could offset the first column by one unit and the narrow both to 5 units..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <p class="text-center program-head">Programs</p>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="text-center">
                <img alt="" class="resize-image" id="image1" src=
                "//placehold.it/300">
                <p class="program-text">Creative Writing</p>
                <p>This will help unleash a childs mind throught their own
                words. The imagination has no limit to a young childs mind.
                this is future forever in life yes hold me
                now</p><button class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="text-center">
                <img alt="" class="resize-image" id="image2" src=
                "//placehold.it/300">
                <p class="program-text">Improv &amp; Comedy</p>
                <p>This improv class is a fun and non-stressful way to
                encourage children and young adults to communicate and
                build confidence! Students will learn how to think on their
                feet when expanding on an idea, story, or debate. These
                classes are inspired by <a href=
                "">Zip Zap
                Zop</a></p><button class="btn btn-primary">Learn
                More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/KRPiGeNSpm